# Ubuntu detects wrong GPU model

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics

I have a relatively old setup which was running with a Nvidia 9500GS GPU, and everything was working properly. Please keep in mind that I am only using one GPU the whole time, I do not want to run a dual setup whatsoever

A couple of days ago I got a Geforce GTS 450 and since then I have tried to get it to run. When I exchanged the GPUs (9500 out - 450 in) it Ubuntu was still recognizing the GPU as a 9500, and it would not let me install the newest drivers. The 9500 was running on the nvidia-340 drivers, and the Nvidia website recommends me the 390 drivers for the 450. (Clarification on this: when I go to the Nvidia website and I enter the model of my GPU, it prompts me to download a file called `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.87.run`. I did not execute this .run file as many people here say that is the wrong way to install the drivers, something I fail to understand because how would a company like Nvidia not test the drivers with all Ubuntu versions, but that discussion would be off-topic here).

I have tried following steps:

Purging the nvidia drivers with `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`, adding the repository with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and then `sudo apt-get update`, installing the 390 drivers with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-390`, then rebooting. This only got me to the login loop, so I had to purge the drivers again. After a reboot the GPU now shows as a GeForce 9400 GT, as shown in the result of `lspci -nnv`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9400 GT] [10de:0641] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. G96 [GeForce 9400 GT] [1043:82be]
    Physical Slot: 2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Memory at f2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

The result of `sudo lshw -C display` is the same:

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G96 [GeForce 9400 GT]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:f2000000-f2ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:2000(size=128)
```

I read that maybe it could be an issue with the PCI database, so I downloaded the newest snapshot with `sudo update-pciids` with no luck. I checked the database and found an [entry](http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/10de/0dc6) for the Nvidia 450 GS, so the problem remains that Ubuntu just does not recognize the GPU correctly.

For the record, I also tried running the .run file from Nvidia I downloaded above, and I got following warnings:

```
The NVIDIA GeForce 9400 GT GPU installed in this system is          
           supported through the NVIDIA 340.xx legacy Linux graphics drivers.  
           Please visit http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html for more        
           information.  The 390.87 NVIDIA Linux graphics driver will ignore   
           this GPU.

WARNING: You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported by the 390.87     
           NVIDIA Linux graphics driver installed in this system.  For further 
           details, please see the appendix SUPPORTED NVIDIA GRAPHICS CHIPS in 
           the README available on the Linux driver download page at           
           www.nvidia.com.
```

I tried these steps on 16.04 LTS, and now have upgraded to 18.04.1 LTS with the hope it would get solved, but again, to no avail.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: If you [google the PCI ID 1043:82be](https://www.google.no/search?q=1043%3A82be), the results is an Asus-manufactured nVidia 9400 GT, which is what Ubuntu identifies it as. Are you 100% certain that this is wrong, and that the card is in fact a GTS 450? 10de:0641 shows up as a 9400 as well...

Comment: Before you commented I would have said I was 120% sure. After reading it I double checked the serial numbers printed on the card and, voilà, you are right. I have been bamboozled. The card is indeed a 9400GT, and it was in the box of a GTS450. WHO DOES THAT. Seriously. If you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you google the PCI ID 1043:82be, the results is an Asus-manufactured nVidia 9400 GT, which is what Ubuntu identifies it as. 10de:0641 shows up as a 9400 as well...

Are you 100% certain that this is wrong, and that the card is in fact a GTS 450?